# Getting a variable from another class file

Tags: c#

I have two class files, one for my main form and calling things and another for my image processing code. My problem is that I create a `Bitmap` in the method in `Class2` and I need it for `Class1` to set the `PictureBox`.

```cs
public void Render(string bmpPath, decimal _Alpha, decimal _Red, decimal _Green, decimal _Blue)
{
    Bitmap imageFile = new Bitmap(bmpPath);
}
```

I just need to send it the bitmap but I don't know how to do that correctly. I tried creating another `Bitmap` but I need the Width and Height.

Comment: `decimal` type for RGB components? Really? Why?

Comment: Getting a variable from another class FILE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the method a *function*. The characteristic of a function is that it returns an object for somebody else to use, in this case class1.

```
public Bitmap Render(string bmpPath, decimal _Alpha, decimal _Red, decimal _Green, decimal _Blue)
{
    Bitmap imageFile = new Bitmap(bmpPath);
    return imagefile;
}
```

And now from Class1 (the Form)

```
var class2 = new Class2();
pictureBox1.Image = class2.Render(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return `Bitmap` instead of `void` from the method.

```
public Bitmap Render(string bmpPath, decimal _Alpha, decimal _Red, decimal _Green, decimal _Blue)
{
    Bitmap imageFile = new Bitmap(bmpPath);
    return imageFile;
}
```

In calling class (Class1)

```
Class2 class2 = new Class2();
pictureBox1.Image = class2.Render(/*your parameter passed here*/);
```

Comment: How would I go about calling it? (I'm new)

Answer (score 0):

Call the Method `Render` from class1 in your class 2 and change the method to return the new image:

```
public Bitmap Render(string bmpPath, decimal _Alpha, decimal _Red, decimal _Green, decimal _Blue)
{
     return new Bitmap(bmpPath);
}
```